# Books/subjects for proof practice

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, self-learning, learning

So I want to practice writing proofs. I've studied general proof-writing but now I want to learn how to apply that to mathematics. From what I understand, the best and most accessible subjects for that are point-set topology and abstract algebra. I have a book for the latter but what about the former? Which books are good for learning how to write a mathematical proof? I understand that the strategies can differ wildly from area to area but please try to bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

You should practice more and more.

**(1)** 2000 Solved Problems in Discrete Mathematics by Seymour Lipschutz (Oct 1, 1991).

**(2)** The Nuts and Bolts of Proofs, Third Edition: An Introduction to Mathematical Proofs, Antonella Cupillari.

Comment: Can you write few words about content of these books?

Answer (score 1):

I've read parts of "How to Prove It: A Structured Approach" by Daniel J. Velleman and I found this book very approachable. Title of the book describes content very accurately. Author explains how to recognize different kinds of theorems and which proof strategy to use. Every proof is structured according to some proof strategy e.g.

- proving implication
- proving logical equivalence
- proving conjunction
- using reduction ad absurdum